# grabbing another column value through a window in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Suppose we have data like this:

```
id type    low_date upper_date
1 Obsolete 2020-01-01 null
1 Ext      2019-01-01 null
2 Obsolete 2023-01-01 null
2 Ext      2018-01-01 null
```

I want to transform this table so as to have the `low_date` of `Obsolete` as the upper_date of `Ext`, for their respective `ids`.

Desired result:

```
id type    low_date upper_date
1 Obsolete 2020-01-01 null
1 Ext      2019-01-01 2020-01-01
2 Obsolete 2023-01-01 null
2 Ext      2018-01-01 2023-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using window function `LAG()`, This function gets the previous row value for a specific column.

```
select id, type, low_date, lag(low_date) over (partition by id order by low_date desc) as upper_date
from mytable
```

This is an other way using `LEFT JOIN` :

```
select t.id, t.type, t.low_date, s.low_date
from mytable t
left join (
  select id, type, low_date
  from mytable
  where type = 'Obsolete'
) as s on s.id = t.id and s.type <> t.type
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/E4jn8By1)